# htaccess rule with multiple similar lines

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create a htaccess rule for our Wordpress site but not sure how I make it run across multiple similar matches.

We have the following old categories on our blog…

```
http://www.example.com/category/this-is-cat-number-one/
http://www.example.com/category/this-is-cat-number-two/
http://www.example.com/category/this-is-cat-number-three/
http://www.example.com/category/this-is-cat-number-four/
```

I'm trying to create a rule that matches everything that looks like…

```
http://www.example.com/category/this-is-cat-number-
```

and redirects it to…

```
http://www.example.com/category/all-numbers/
```

At the moment I have this but it's not working…

```
RewriteRule ^\/category\/this-is-cat-number-(.*) /category/all-numbers/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^\/category\/this-is-cat-number-(.*)$ /category/all-numbers/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

You missed `$` which indicates the end of regular expression.